# WCF hosted in windows service errors

Tags: windows, wcf, service, host

I have a WCF in VB which is to be hosted in a Windows Service. I managed the install program so the service actually installs. But, when I try to start the service, I get the following error:

> The service on Local Computer started
>   and then stopped. Some services stop
>   automatically if they have no work to
>   do, for example, the Performance Logs
>   and Alerts service.

Cheking the Event Viewer gives me the following:

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ArgumentException: ServiceHost
>   only supports class service types.
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2&
>   implementedContracts).........

Anybody have any ideas what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code.. how you are opening the service host?

Comment: did this actually work?

Comment: Hi AJ - It's been a while, but I checked the first answer below after doing a little research. David Steele was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServiceHost constructor must be concrete implementation of service contract.

It sounds like you are passing in the Interface rather than the service implementation.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Do you mean the install program???

Answer (score 1):

```
  svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MCWCFService.MCManagementService));
  svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
          typeof(MCWCFService.IMCManagementService),
          new NetTcpBinding(),
          "net.tcp://192.168.0.2:8011");
  svh.Open();
```

When creating the ServiceHost use the Class name - in the above it is MCManagementService. In the endpoint, use the interface - in the above it is IMCManagementService.